# How to return a single char from a function

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to programming; I am in an intro to c++ course in college.

How would I go about returning a single char from a function back to the main? I haven't seen any posts that answer this question simply enough for me to understand.

Thanks in advance!

For those interested, this is the code that I wrote that caused me to ask this question.
(NOTE: My prof tells us to include cstdlib and iostream in all programs, and to put `using namespace std` before the main. I already saw several posts that say not to use this, but this is how my prof has us write our programs.)

```
char evaluate(int score){
/*receives an int score out of 100 from main  and determines what letter grade to return */
if (score >= 90 && score <= 100)
  return "A";
else if (score >= 80 && score <= 89)
  return "B";
else if (score >= 70 && score <= 79)
  return "C";
else if (score >= 65 && score <= 65)
  return "D";
else
  return "F";
}
```

When I do this, I get "error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]"

Any ideas why?

Comment: `"A"` is a string literal. `'A'` is a character literal.

Comment: there's a big difference between a single tick and quotation mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"A"` is a string literal. What you meant is `'A'`.

Comment: What exactly is a string literal? Sorry I'm still new to all this stuff

Comment: Characters enclosed in double quotes are usually called as string literals and reside in read only location of memory. So, their type is `const char*` (i.e., pointer to constant char(s)).

Comment: char is a single character type, represented between single quotes. between double quotes are the multiple character type, a string, independently that how many (one or more) characters are enclosed

Answer (score 4):

```
  return "A";
```

will return type `const char*`

You should rather use :-

```
return 'A'
```

to return a character.

Comment: Sorry to bother but what is a 'const char*'? How would I return a regular char?

Comment: As mentioned, replace all `""` in the return statement with a `''`.

Comment: @iceman `const` means that the character cannot be modified. This makes sense, because in your function you have `'A'`, for example, which is not a variable, but a constant. The code that calls your function may stick the result into a variable, and modify it there (that *variable* would not have the `const` qualifier on the type, and therefore not be a constant)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can eliminate multiple return statements by doing this:

```
char evaluate(int score)
{
    char grade;
    if (score >= 90 && score <= 100)
      grade = 'A';
    else if (score >= 80 && score <= 89)
      grade = 'B';
    else if (score >= 70 && score <= 79)
      grade = 'C';
    else if (score >= 65 && score <= 65)
      grade = 'D';
    else
      grade = 'F';
    return grade;
}
```

As others have mentioned, you should use single quotes. `E.g. 'A'` instead of double quotes. Use double for strings. Single quotes for `char`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
char evaluate(int score){
char returnValue = 'F';
/*receives an int score out of 100 from main  and determines what letter grade to return */
if (score >= 90 && score <= 100)
  returnValue = 'A';
else if (score >= 80 && score <= 89)
  returnValue = 'B';
else if (score >= 70 && score <= 79)
  returnValue = 'C';
else if (score >= 65 && score <= 65)
  returnValue = 'D';

return returnValue;
}
```